# How do I play Sid Meier's Pirates! in a windowed mode?

Tags: sid-meiers-pirates

Is it possible to play Sid Meier's Pirates in a windowed mode? I know I need to edit config.ini but otherwise I'm clueless.

I bought the game from the GameStop website if that helps. When I open my config file it says that it is a shortcut and is always blank no matter how I save it.

- Do I have to make a copy and save it?
- Is there an original copy that I have to edit?
- Can I not edit it because I bought it from the GameStop website?
- Does it matter what type of computer you have?

Comment: I believe you could add a switch to the target path for windowed. I'll try later tonight and report back

Comment: @user61635 you could fight to reopen this question if you change it to `How can I play Sid Meier's Pirates! in Windowed Mode?` and removed the stuff about recording, but otherwise FRAPS is the one that actually will catch the process and record the game output without having to edit any files.

Answer (score 7):

**SYSTEM PATHS MAY VARY!**

> The game doesn’t have a default windowed mode so you have to edit the config file to make this possible. You can find this config file by going to your home directory and navigating to Library/Preferences/Firaxis Games/Sid Meier’s Pirates/My Games/Game. Open the "Config.ini" file with TextEdit and add the line "fullscreen = 0" to the bottom of the list. Then save the change you just made to this file, quit text edit, and you’re ready to go. Obviously you’ll want to make sure the game’s resolution is set lower than that of your monitor’s resolution or else the window won’t fit. For example, my monitor is set to "1344 x 840" and I set Pirates to "1280 x 800".

[Source](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090706141034AAQ2GvL)

I remembered having to do this once.

It all depends on where your SAVE file is located. Be sure to check your documents FIRST then the SteamApps folder, as this would be the install dir, NOT THE SAVE DIR!

For Windows Users:

Hold WinKey+R then type `notepad.exe C:\Users\{YOUR USERNAME HERE}\Documents\Firaxis Games\Sid Meier's Pirates\My Games\Game\Config.ini`

IF NOTEPAD CANNOT FIND THE FILE THEN START SEARCHING:

For windows Vista and up: `C:\Users\{YOUR USERNAME HERE}\Documents\Firaxis Games\Sid Meier’s Pirates\My Games\Game` **MAY BE** your path.

It may also be in `C:\Program Files(x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\`

For Windows XP and below (Cause We're all hipsters/old farts that way): `C:\Documents and Settings\{YOUR USERNAME HERE}\My Documents\Firaxis Games\Sid Meier’s Pirates\My Games\Game`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12237/discussion-between-user61635-and-cole-busby)

Comment: Great, that worked! Could set the resolution to 1920x1080 and it worked perfectly. Thankyou!